# Laravel - Insert Selected Row

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have a table :

| header 1 | header 2 | button |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | insert |
| Second | row | insert |
| Third | row | insert |

I want when the insert button is clicked, the row with that button is inserted in the database.
So far I have in the controller :

```
function submitData(Request $request) {

        $data = new Data;
        $data->detail = $request->input('ft');
        $data->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $data->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $data->save();
```

And in blade :

```
<form id="regForm" action="{{route('sendDate')}}" method="post" >
    @csrf
<tbody id="myTable">
@foreach($features as $feature)
<tr>
<td>{{ $feature->detail }}</td>
<input type="hidden" class="h-form-control" name="ft" value="{{ $feature->detail }}" >
<td>
<button type="submit" form="regForm" > insert </button>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

But the *last* row is inserted whatever button is clicked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using an array so all your previous inputs will be replaced by the last one. If you don't have any more fields to send with your request you can solve this by putting your form inside your loop. `button` tag also accepts a value so you can skip the hidden input field to use less code.

```
@foreach($features as $feature)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $feature->detail }}</td>
    <td>row</td>
    <td>
        <form action="{{route('sendDate')}}" method="post" >
            @csrf
            <button type="submit" name="ft" value="{{ $feature->detail }}" > insert</button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: When I put the form inside the loop, the sumbit button does not work.. Even tried to activate the button from *JS* script after the document is loaded with `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {..}`

Comment: You need to remove `id` from the form and the `form` attribute on the button if you haven't done so or make them unique.

Comment: Oh my bad I had put `form` just after `foreach`.. Thank you very much it work as wanted !